# Phpbb forums join toghether with same topic

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, forum, phpbb

I am dealing with special task. As a user, moderator and admin of PHPBB 3.0.10 forum I'm tryin to solve the clue:

how to add to my forum topics and users from another forum. The catch is that this second forums database and files is from different server. Of course i have the keys to the server and database.

I was reading guides how to create double connection in php, but i haven't any clue how to transform it for phpbb forums. Is it possible to do somehow? There is no special mods for this situation

Anyone can tell me what steps should I make?

Comment: this second forum is also phpbb 3

Comment: So do you want to merge two forums? Or do you want to run two forums simultaneously on the same server?

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of precision - I want to run two forums simultaneusly. Sharing the part of topics on both forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this once back with phpBB 2 - at that time they had a great knowledgebase article describing how to do exactly that. [I dug up the link](http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/share-members%2Bsessions%2Bbans%2Bacross-multiple-phpbb-boards/) for you. This article was written back in 2007, though - not sure how relevant is to phpBB 3. May be worth a look regardless.

However, I would imagine the general idea is the same. On one boards, define MySQL connection info for the opposite board, and edit `constants.php` to point to it. That should effectively make board #2 pull data from #1.

Comment: I will do my best using your advice! :)